# How to fire the autocomplete after input reach 3 characters

Tags: forms

I am setting a view for the autocomplete feature of a widget with the following code:

```
function my_module_field_widget_entity_reference_autocomplete_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context)
{
  $field_name = $context['items']->getName();
  if ($field_name == 'my_field_name') {
    $element['target_id']['#selection_handler'] = 'views';
    $element['target_id']['#selection_settings']['view'] = [
      'view_name' => 'a_wiew_id',
      'display_name' => 'a_display_name_id',
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
    ];
  }
}
```

Is-it possible to add a key/value to `#selection_settings` to fire the autocomplete only if the user have typed 3 characters? (or any other idea)